# Passwordless login (from physical console and from others users)

Tags: users, login, password

How to configure a user (in Debian) to login without password?

A user without password needs to login in physical terminals (ttys - not pty) either using `su - user` from another user, without being asked for password.

(security isn't a requirement in this environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensuring that the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` has only module args `nullok` instead of `nullok_secure`, allows users to login without password when the user doesn't have any password set.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question at first.  If you just need to alter a user to have no password, you can just run

```
sudo passwd -d <name of user>
```

Alternatively, if you only plan on logging in to the password-less user using `su`, just run it like this:

```
`sudo su <user>`
```

You will have to enter your password for `sudo`, as per usual, unless you alter the `/etc/sudoers` file using a `sudo visudo` command in the following way:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

should become:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)NOPASSWD: ALL
```

where the `%sudo` may be a differently named group in other linux distros, such as `%wheel` in archlinux.  Note, that this modification will make it so that no `sudo` commands need a password, system-wide.

Comment: I don't want an auto-login, but just a login without asking for password, for certain users.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer, to match your question.

Comment: This keep asking the password with "su - user" even if I try to log from a text console, the Debian ask the password, and the user haven't a password. This was one think I already tried.

Comment: Ah... yes I've never had any success calling `su` directly before with debian or ubuntu, even when I have a valid password.  I will edit the answer again.